# Statistically significant definition of power

Tags: statistical-power, frequentist

After a not-quick literature research I noticed that there are two types od definition for what power is: 
One is: it's the probability of not making type II error' (**A**)
The other is: it is the probability of getting a statistically significant result. (**B**)

I am bothered by the second one - is it right or wrong?

A little context here:
Probably (p>.99) all of us know about Fisher's and Neyman's approach to statistics. *Power* is something coming from frequentism. *Statistically significant* term is coming from the Fisherian school. These two approaches can't be used interchangeably, (however, they are) nor their components can. So my thought is, that the second one definition is like marrying Fisher and Neyman, again, just on a different level. What does "statistical significancy" have to do with the power of a test? 
Is is a kind of twisted, mental shortcut?

What do you think?

Comment: Where are you seeing (B) stated that way? (B) is equivalent to (A) if the alternative hypothesis is true, otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: Power is about whether or not you reject a null hypothesis that is in fact false.  In order to reject the null, you need a "statistically significant" result.   If the result is statistically significant, you reject the null, otherwise you don't.  So it's not a twisted, mental shortcut, it's fundamental to the calculation of power.

Comment: @BryanKrause "Power is the probability of finding a significant effect when the alternative hypothesis is true" - An article titled "A power fallacy" by EJWagenmakers

Comment: @jbowman It's not just about numbers that agree (usually if the power is high the result is significant), but as they, the numbers, don't know where they come from, I think that is the matter of the coincidence. The philosophies that stay behind those terms (statistical significance and power) are different. Therefore the B definition is twisted.

Comment: One important fact these sorts of word-definitions often completely miss is that power depends on the *specific* alternative under consideration. Typically when a document insists on defining power only in words, you're in a situation where the alternative is composite rather than simple, but the statement of the definition *acts as if it were simple*. This can be observed to directly mislead statistically naive readers -- the very people it is written for -- over and over. To me it's therefore bad pedagogy --

Comment: -- not only does it fail to explain something important at exactly the moment it should be made clear, it actively leads students away from the correct notion. When one is writing about power mathematically, this is much less of an issue, but the need for slightly more involved phrasing to correctly express it in words is a very poor reason to omit it altogether. If you want power to be "*a* probability...", you need to specify *exactly which alternative you're talking about*. If you want to talk about power when the alternative is composite, the discussion should focus on the *power function*

Answer (score 3):

> One is: it's the probability of not making type II error' (A)

A type II error, in this context, is "accepting a null hypothesis that is false." Power is the probably of "not that" which would be "rejecting a null hypothesis that is false."

> The other is: it is the probability of getting a statistically significant result. (B)

This statement is missing an important piece from the full quote you added in a comment:

> Power is the probability of finding a significant effect when the alternative hypothesis is true

This can be restated as "rejecting a null hypothesis that is false" because finding a significant effect means rejecting the null, and the alternative hypothesis being true means the null hypothesis is false.

They are the same definition of power.

Comment: What about Fisher and Neyman?

Comment: @Lil'Lobster Modern NHST is an imperfect combination of the two schools. "What about Fisher and Neyman" is a topic over which much ink has been spilled, if that's the real battle you want to wage there are other existing answers here to start with.